# Run code on the server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, serverside-javascript

I'm trying to create a multiplayer game on yur browser.
And I need to send messages from server to all clients every few seconds.
I have no idea how can I run a script on server side?
Sorry, I'm a complete newbie :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what is your server technology. If you have no choice yet, go for node.js (and express) as your server technology and use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for real time messaging. Have a look in the Getting Started section. They have a chat demo and a collaborative white board demo which are in a way similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Meir, I'm going to try to create the chat demo with socket.io.

Comment: BTW does anyone know how to setup socket.io on wamp?

Comment: I think what I referenced you to is for node.js. If you'd rather use WAMP, look for a relevant module.